# Swfit: Firebase DB / Dictionary look for highest Int

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, nsdictionary

I have a Firebase database which looks like in the image[image]

When I get these values in my code via a NSDictionary, I want to check what is the highest integer, so in this case 4.

This is how the NSdictionary looks (I can't do dictionaryName[ 1 ] like when I have an array  to get the value so...):

```
  {
   1 =     {
      driverName = chauffeur1;
      latitude = "37.33022769";
      longitude = "-122.03439793";
  };
  4 =     {
      driverName = kees;
  };
}
```

Is there any option in Firebase or in Dictionary's which could help me to get this functional?
I've already looked up some solutions but all of them were not what I was looking for. Maybe someone knows how to?

I'll be glad to know

Edit 1:
The problem is that I get my Dictionary from firebase like this:

```
DBProvider.Instance.dbRef.child("driverLocations").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary {
            print(data)
            let keys = data.allKeys
            let sortedKeys = Array(keys).sorted(by: { $0 > $1 }) // highest will be the first
            let highestKey = sortedKeys[0]
        }
    })
```

I can't typ it like:

```
 if let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary[Int: Any]
```

Maybe I'm just a little bit stupid doing it wrong.. Do you know how I can fix it?

Edit 2 (snapshot.value data)

```
Optional({
1 =     {
    driverName = chauffeur1;
    latitude = "37.33193453";
    longitude = "-122.03777128";
};
4 =     {
    driverName = kees;
};
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this.

```
if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [Int:[String:Any]] {
    if let max = Array(dictionary.keys).max() {
        print(dictionary[max])
    }
}
```

If your dictionary have `key` as `String` with number try like this.

```
if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String:[String:Any]] {
    if let max = Array(dictionary.keys).flatMap({ Int($0) }).max() {
        print(dictionary["\(max)"])
    }
}
```

Comment: you should also change the dictionary declaration to `[Int:[String:Any]]`

Comment: @LeoDabus I have add dictionary declaration for just ex but your suggestion is also good edited answer for that.

Comment: Yeah. I think your answer is better. @royvano check this

Comment: Yess this works! @VladPulichev , the Int was meant to be a string :)

Comment: Well, I used the whole code of @VladPulichev , but from your code I took the [string:[string:any]] section, I can only accept one so it's pretty difficult.. What should I do, I don't want both of you to feel not appreciated..

Comment: @royvano But why you need sorting also if `[string:[string:any]]` has solved your issue that is suggest by me you need to accept my one. Have you try once like my answer with max no need to go for sort

Comment: I don't use your code, I like the sorting better but because your answer suggest the right [String:[String:Any]] I accepted yours.

Comment: @royvano It is Ok that you like sorting but batter if you convert your string key to number before sorting other wise with string order of number will be  1,10,11,2,20,21,3... and so on hope you understand what i'm saying

Comment: @royvano just to let you know that if you approach it as I suggested it doesn't matter how you declare your dictionaries keys. String or Int they would both work. Actually You don't even have to declare the dictionary type. Xcode can infer the type automatically.

Comment: You can also sort your dictionary directly, the result it is an array of tuples `[(Key,Value)]`

Comment: @LeoDabus You are right but dictionary is coming from firebase so we need to specify its type.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
let yourDictionary = [Int: Any]() // or [String: Any]()
let keys = yourDictionary.keys
let sortedKeys = Array(keys).sorted(by: { $0 > $1 }) // highest will be the first
let highestKey = sortedKeys[0]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I really like your answer, but the compiler says that '>' can't be applied to two 'Any' operands..

Comment: @royvano your dictionary should be let yourDictionary = [Int:Any]()

Comment: @royvano just change the dictionary declaration to `[Int:[String:Any]]` your dictionary key is Int and the value is another dictionary

Comment: @VladPulichev Thanks for your detailed answer, but I forgot to mention where de dictionary comes from. I've updated my question, could you maybe please check what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @royvano Have you tried like I have mentioned in the comment on your question?

Comment: @royvano type not if let data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary { , type if let data = snapshot.value as? [Int: Any]{

Comment: @VladPulichev Thanks, But then it says that data has no member allkeys.. I think that's the only problem now

Comment: @royvano type .keys

Comment: @royvano and pls think a little bit yourself:)

Comment: @VladPulichev I wish I could, I'm very new with dictionary's and I couldn't find it on google.. I'm very glad I can learn those things by persons like you! 1 sec I'll try everything

Comment: @royvano Check my below answer I have edited for you

Comment: So I tried it, but It doesn't accept the "if let data = snapshot.value as? [Int:[String:Any]] " or "if let data = snapshot.value as? [Int: Any]". In my thinking the first one should work. But is it possible it only accepts NSDictionary? 

When I print snapshot.value it is giving me the good data which looks like in edit 2 in my question

Comment: @VladPulichev It works I get the highest value which is 4, I'm really thankfull thanks!!!

Comment: @royvano glad to hear

Comment: @VladPulichev I'm so sorry but I've to accept Nirav D his answer, you helped me better but his answer did suggest [String:[String:any]], hope you don't mind cause you helped me better ...

Comment: @royvano its ok! Main thing, that you have received answer:)

Answer (score 1):

```
let dict = ["1": ["driverName": "chauffeur1",
                "latitude": 37.33022769,
                "longitude": -122.03439793],
            "4": ["driverName": "kees"]]

if let maxElememt = dict.max(by: { $0.key<$1.key }) {
    maxElememt.key    // "4"
    maxElememt.value    // ["driverName": "kees"]
}

let maxValue = dict.max{$0.key<$1.key}.map{$0.value}
maxValue   // ["driverName": "kees"]
```

if you need it just sorted by your keys decreasing their value

```
let sortedDic = dict.sorted{ $0.key>$1.key }

sortedDic.first          //  (key "4", ["driverName": "kees"])
sortedDic.first?.key     //  "4"
sortedDic.first?.value   // ["driverName": "kees"]
sortedDic.first?.value["driverName"] // "kees"
```